# Rails: Using Yield, Calling Multiple View Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yield, content-for

**Problem: How Do You Render Multiple View Pages From Different Controllers?**

In my **views/layouts/application.html.erb**, I call **views/posts/index.html.erb** with the yield method.

```
<div class='span10'>
    <%= yield %>
</div>
```

On top of it, I wanted to call **views/good_posts/index.html.erb** with yield. So in that particular index file, I wrap around all the code with content_for method.

```
<%= content_for :good_post do %> all my content in good_post/index.html.erb <% end %>
```

I go back to application.html.erb, I tried to call the index file of good_post with yield method.

```
<div class='span10'>
    <%= yield :good_post %>
</div>
<div class='span10'>
    <%= yield %>
</div>
```

I thought this would result in good_post/index to be rendered on top of post/index, but it did not work; only post/index was correctly rendered as before. Could someone explain why this is, and tell me the correct way to approach this problem? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you using caching? `content_for` is ignored in that case. Otherwise, try `<%= content_for :good_post %>` instead of `<%= yield :good_post %>`. Both are valid, but see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I thought you have to use yield AND content_for at the same time. That's why I did content_for in good_posts/index, and to call this file, I did yield from the application.html.

Comment: You have to use `content_for` when _defining_ the content, as you did. You can use either `content_for` or `yield` when _rendering_ the content. See [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for)

Comment: I see. I tried, but it did not work. Still trying hard to figure out a way to include the index.html from good_posts view to the application layout...

Comment: You could always just work around this by factoring the content of `good_posts/index.html.erb` into a partial in, say `good_posts/_posts.html.erb`, and using `<%= render 'good_posts/posts' %>` in `good_posts/index.html.erb` and `posts/index.html.erb`

Comment: Thank you! It worked. The one additional thing I had to do was defining local variables that were defined in GoodPostController in the partial again. Otherwise, you would get a "local variable doesn't exist" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, as @cdesrosiers said, rename the `index.html.erb` file in `good_posts` to `_index.html.erb`. Then you can render this view in your application like this:

```
<div class='span10'>
    <%= render 'good_posts/index' %>
    <%= yield :good_post %>
</div>
<div class='span10'>
    <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Personally, I would change the `index.html.erb` file in `good_posts` folder to `_good_posts.html.erb` file in `app/views/posts` folder. Your code will have better meaning, and you can know where to find it after, because it relates to `posts`. So, if you change this, use this code:

```
<div class='span10'>
    <%= render 'posts/good_posts' %=
    <%= yield :good_post %>
</div>
<div class='span10'>
    <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Another you should change is `content_for :good_post` -> `content_for :good_posts` , because good posts maybe have many posts, so you should use post in pluralize.